# Alternative DOM property for scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, autoresize

Is there any other way to get the inner height of a certain HTML Element without using scrollHeight?

The things is that I have a table with 100 records and in each record i resize a certain textarea within a columns using height=0 then height=scrollHeight.

the problem is IE executes the scrollHeight for atleast 20 ~ 50ms depends on the size and I have about 100 records. That means, just for IE to render all the records it would take more than 6 seconds just for load 100 records, what if I need to load 100 records? that would ruin my website.

So I am asking if there is any alternative for scrollHeight or maybe is you could provide any alternative code that resizes textarea.

Thanks is advance,

**UPDATE**

This is what i get from IE UI Responsiveness
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Second Image: as you can see in the image below, the problem why IE is slow in getting just the scrollHeight of a certain element (textarea) is because it calculates the whole Layout (html body) instead of just getting the scrollHeight of that particular Element (the textarea element)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are going row by row, reading `scrollHeight` then setting `height`. This is prohibitively expensive, because each read after a write is triggering reflow in order to give you an accurate answer (because the write might have changed something on the page that would influence the value being read). It is not `height=scrollHeight` that takes time; it is the reflow that is necessary in order for it to do it.

```
layout (write height of all: 0)

reflow
read scrollHeight
write height

reflow (!)
read scrollHeight
write height

reflow (!)
read scrollHeight
write height
...

reflow (!)
paint
```

(Or maybe you set `height` to 0 in each iteration; it doesn't matter, as successive writes are not triggering reflow.)

Instead, try to do it in a batch. Read all of the `scrollHeight` values into an array; then, when you have them all, set them all. This way, you will only get two reflows: once when you start reading, and once when you are done with your code and the browser needs to show the page, because, as long as you are just reading or just writing, no reflows are needed - only when you cross from writing to reading values.

```
layout (write height of all: 0)

reflow
read scrollHeight
read scrollHeight
...
write height
write height

reflow
paint
```

**EDIT:** This is a hack; I am not that good in Knockout yet. But as a minimal example of what is possible, if you can't do it any other way, it might do. You will probably want to run it and stretch to "Full Page", or you won't be able to see anything :)

```js
var vm = {
  list: ko.observableArray(["foo", "bar\nbaz", "1\n2\n3\n4"])
};

var updatedHeights;

ko.bindingHandlers.autoresizeStart = {
  update: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
    var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    console.log("start update; setting updateHeights to []");
    updatedHeights = [];
  }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.autoresize = {
  update: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
    console.log("mid update;", elem, "is updated, so let's remember its scrollHeight");
    updatedHeights.push([elem, elem.scrollHeight]);
  }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.autoresizeEnd = {
  update: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
    var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    console.log("end update; lets set heights for all updated elements:");
    updatedHeights.forEach(function(elemWithHeight) {
      console.log("  ", elemWithHeight[1], elemWithHeight[0]);
      elemWithHeight[0].style.height = elemWithHeight[1] + "px";
    });
    console.log("all done :)");
  }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.autoresizeStart = true;
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.autoresizeEnd = true;


ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.list.push("a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko autoresizeStart: list --><!-- /ko -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
  <li >
    <textarea data-bind="text: $data, autoresize: $data"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- ko autoresizeEnd: list --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: it maybe possible but the thing is that I use knockout js. Then I created a autoResizeHeight custom binding. my records is in a Items() observableArray property. so it would actually loop each items.

Comment: check my update, base on the screenshot. i have 2 separate call for scrollHeight but the second call ms is not that very far from my first call exec time

Comment: So the pattern is as I predict - you have `style.height = 0` (a write) followed by `scrollHeight` (a read). This triggers reflow. I am not sure how to work it out with your custom binding, but basically you would want to have two passes: one where you render the heights of all elements to zero, then when they are all rendered, set them all to scrollHeight.

Comment: I removed the height=0 but still the height=scrollHeight is still slow.

Comment: You would need to remove the read/write/read/write pattern. Before you had "write height", "read scrollHeight", "write height", "write height", "read scrollHeight", "write height"; getting rid of *one* "write height" will not cut it, you still have striped reads and writes.

Comment: I added a minimal example using Knockout; you should be able to replicate it easily. There may be a better way to do this, but I don't know how. I hope it helps you.

Comment: hmmm, ok, thank you very much I will try those binding, I'll get back about the result :)